# FileNotFoundException errors

Tags: java, java-io, fileinputstream

Sorry for the bad title, can't think of a better one.

I am currently in this *contradicting* problem with **FileNotfoundException** where my file is located via a command `file.getCanonicalPath()` and when using the `FileInputStream` method. I get a **FileNotFoundException**.

Below are the codes I used:

```
File file = new File("members.s");
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CWA2\\members.s");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        byte[] b=new byte[fileIn.available()];
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            m.add(mem = (Member)in.readObject());
        }
```

This is the output and exception errors I get.

```
    C:\Users\users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CWA2\members.s
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CWA2\members.s (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at Demos.DeserializeDemo.main(DeserializeDemo.java:21)
```

So I am abit confused. How is it that the `file.getCanonicalPath()` method can locate the file I want to use, but the `FileInputStream` returns an error. Can anyone help me on thiS?

Comment: Are you sure the exception matches to your code? You use `C:\\Users\\lxLionHartxl\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CWA2\\members.s` to create the Stream, but your exception is about `C:\Users\users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CWA2\members.s`. That's not the same path.

Comment: try removing double slashes from your path.

Comment: @pathfinder2104 the double slashes are for escaping the backslashes. In java, a backslash is an escape character and therefore to use a backslash you need to escape it with a second backslash

Comment: @MaxMeijer Yeah forgot in windows its a backward slash ... :) :) thanx

Comment: You can just write `"C:/Users/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CWA2/members.s"` afaik.

Comment: There is a specific warning in the [Javadoc for `InputStream.available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()): "It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."

Comment: can u just try this FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file.getCanonicalPath());   ????

Comment: Why are you constructing a File, getting its canonical path, and then not making any use of either of them? If the File corresponds to anything in the real world, you should just be able to use new FileInputStream(file), and if it doesn't it's pointless to construct it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file.getCanonicalPath()` would just return `"members.s"` as its path and not the full path.
`getCaninicalPath()` removes redundant `.` or `..` from the pathname.

Because `FileInputStream` takes `File` as its argument (also a string btw) and `File` takes a `String` as argument.

```
File file = new File("members.s");
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());

FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CWA2\\members.s");
```

This should be

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CWA2\\members.s");
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Answer (score -1):

This exception will be thrown, when a file with the specified pathname does not exist or if the file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible, for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only file for writing.